# stopifnot when using fwrite (datable error)

Tags: r, data.table

Trying to use `fwrite` to export a csv I got the following error:

> Error in stopifnot(is.list(x), ncol(x) > 0L, identical(quote, "auto")
>   ||  :    4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3

I tried to re-install the package but nothing works.

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: This is very simple, fwrite(test,’test.csv’) where test is a data table. Is is related to a bug in the package?

Comment: Also add `dput(test)` output to your question if it's possible